# Typescript + Next.js not type checking function parameters/arguments

Tags: javascript, typescript, duck-typing, structural-typing

I am working on a project with typescript & next.js, and for some reason types for function arguments are not being checked.

I have provided a code sample below, for which I expect the function call to complain about me providing a `string` instead of an `SExpr`.

```js
abstract class SExpr {
  abstract toString(): string
}

function parse(expr: SExpr) {
  // ...
}

parse('123') // does not complain - compiles just fine
```

I have never experienced such an issue before, and have tried my best to find an option to change in `tsconfig.json` to resolve this issue, but unfortunately have not been able to fix it.

At this point I suspect that next.js might be overriding my `tsconfig.json` or the like, as I've never had any problems when just using typescript.

My `tsconfig.json` is as follows:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Comment: Hi! Please add some sort of standalone code sample to your question that reproduces the issue. Without a repro, it'll be extremely difficult for folks to help you.

Comment: I added a link to my repo! :)

Comment: This is by design. TypeScript has a structural type system not a nominal one. `SExpr` has only one member, and that member happens to be a member present on all JavaScript objects including strings. In other words, typescript is behaving as expected and you should consider a different approach such as the use of discriminated unions instead of class hierarchies to represent things like expressions.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Ah that makes a lot of sense, thank you! Feel free to post an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: @Tim Please see [mre].  In short though, links aren't good enough; the question should be able to stand on its own, without depending on an ourside resource that you can delete at any time.

Comment: @Daedalus Thanks for the feedback. I don't post on here often so I didn't know about all the requirements. I just edited my question to include some code that demonstrates my issue on its own :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design.

TypeScript has a structural type system not a nominal one. In the structural type system, `A` is a subtype of `B` if all the members of `B` are provided by `A`. The heritage, of `A` is not a determining factor.

In your case `SExpr` has only one member, a `toString` method that takes no parameters and returns a `string`, and all JavaScript objects provide such a member, including `strings`.

In sum, TypeScript is behaving as intended and you should consider a different approach, such as employing [Discriminated Unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions), instead of class hierarchies to represent the types of the various kinds of expressions your program parses.